# Creating async Global Index in Phoenix

Tags: indexing, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am having trouble creating Async Indices following https://phoenix.apache.org/secondary_indexing.html#Index_Population

The command used to create index:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_TABLE_NAME_START_TIME ON SCHEMANAME.TABLE_NAME(START_TIME) INCLUDE (END_TIME) ASYNC;
```

Command used to start IndexTool:

```
bin/hbase org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.index.IndexTool --schema SCHEMANAME --data-table TABLE_NAME --index-table IDX_TABLE_NAME_START_TIME --output-path ASYNC_IDX_TABLE_NAME_START_TIME_HFILES
```

and getting following exception:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. CHAR types may only contain single byte characters (7ff9d�2Z03725157354996cc593-a)
        at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.index.PhoenixIndexImportMapper.map(PhoenixIndexImportMapper.java:122)
        at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.index.PhoenixIndexImportMapper.map(PhoenixIndexImportMapper.java:48)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
```

Table was created with following command:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMANAME.TABLE_NAME(
  ID CHAR (36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  START_TIME DATE,
  END_TIME DATE,
  SERVICE VARCHAR
);
```

I also tried inserting new data into the table - the upsert succeeded and the index table also had new rows.

Phoenix version: 4.7.0.2.5.0.0-1245
Hbase version: 1.1.2

What could be the cause of the exception and any way to fix it?

Comment: I think it's complaining about CHAR(36).  Try using varchar and see if it works around the problem you see.

Comment: Is there any workaround to get it working for the current table? It has hundreds of millions of rows already!

Comment: Update: Using varchar indeed did work